# What type of knot would allow the length of the standing part of the rope to be adjusted?

Tags: rope-knots

Let's say I'm setting up a pole tent, and I want to be able to tie off the pole to the stake. I want to use a knot that will maintain the length of rope between the pole and the stake, but I may also want to adjust the length without completely retying the knot.

[image: Pole tent example]

In this example image, the length *A* should be adjustable, without untying the rope from the stake or the pole.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tent companies use the [trucker's hitch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trucker%27s_hitch).

Comment: The trucker's hitch provides mechanical advantage while tightening, but being adjustable depend on how you tie off to the loop.

Comment: A "trucker's hitch" is really a strategy for tying rope, not a single knot. I like to use a slip knot for the loop and then a series of half hitches to finish it. There are a ton of advantages trucker's hitches: mechanical advantage, adjustability, easy to tie tightly (i.e. under load), easy to untie.

Comment: I like this method in this situation, as I think it will make it easier to tighten the line. While adjustment does involve untying part of the "knot", the mechanical advantage gained overcomes that disadvantage.

Comment: +1, came to suggest this, but didn't actually know the name of the knot.  For tying things down or making them tight, this is the most useful way to use a rope.

Answer (score 3):

The [Taut-line hitch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taut-line_hitch) is intended for exactly this.

Comment: This is a great knot for this situation, though it doesn't offer any advantage when it comes to actually pulling the line tight.